# In Admin Grid : add hidden column to magento adim product grid

Tags: magento

i am trying to add a hidden column to admin product grid.
is there a way by which we can add hidden column. please provide suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need hidden column?

Comment: i have added category ilter in admin grid which is working flawlessly, but there is one problem these filter wiped out when other filters come's into picture. in short for doing custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding 'no-display' class while adding the column.

The code for this is as below:

```
$this->addColumn('column_name', array(
                'header' => 'Column Header',
                'align' => 'left',
                'width' => '120px',
                'index' => 'column_index',
                'type' => 'text',
                'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
                'header_css_class'=>'no-display'                
            ));
```